# Unable to run "sqoop job --exec" in oozie

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

need some advice I'm trying to run sqoop job in oozie but suddenly it was killed and there's this warning in oozie-error.log

```
2018-01-21 17:30:12,473  WARN SqoopActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[edge01.domain.com] USER[linknet] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000006-180121122345026-oozie-link-W] ACTION[0000006-180121122345026-oozie-link-W@sqoop-node] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
```

job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://hadoop01.domain.com:8020
jobTracker=hadoop01.domain.com:18032
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
examplesRoot=examples
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/share/lib/oozie
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/sqoop
```

workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="sqoop-wf">
    <start to="sqoop-node"/>

    <action name="sqoop-node">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/sqoop"/>
                <mkdir path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <command>job --exec ingest_cpm_alarm</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

And this is how I created sqoop job ingest_cpm_alarm

```
$ sqoop job --create ingest_cpm_alarm -- import --connect jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432/snapshot --username "extractor" -P \
--incremental append \
--check-column snapshot_date \
--table cpm_snr_history \
--as-avrodatafile \
--target-dir /tmp/trash/cpm_alarm
```

I can run this sqoop job successfully but not in Oozie scheduler.
Also, jar file postgresql-42.1.4.jar and everything under $SQOOP_HOME/lib have been copied into libpath directory (/share/lib/oozie).

Oozie and sqoop reside in the same server. In my sqoop-site.xml, I only set these parameters.

```
sqoop.metastore.client.enable.autoconnect=true
sqoop.metastore.client.record.password=true
sqoop.metastore.client.record.password=true
```

Did I miss something here ?

Answer (score 1):

it was resolved, I missed sqoop-site.xml that should be available in the same workflow directory in HDFS.

This post has similar issue:
[sqoop exec job in oozie is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269669/sqoop-exec-job-in-oozie-is-not-working)

Thanks.